# V8: How to use Set method on a Persistent handler?

Tags: v8

I need to set properties on an object referenced by a Persistent handler. However, it seems like Persistent class doesn't have a Set method (unlike the Local class).

Does it mean that Persistent handlers are read only? What is the best way to set a property on a Persistent handler then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `v8::Local` from the `v8::Persistent`, then use that to call operations on the object (`Set` and/or others). Note that you need an active `HandleScope` for this.

```cpp
v8::Persistent<v8::Object> my_persistent = ...;

v8::HandleScope scope(isolate);
v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = v8::Local<v8::Object>::New(isolate, my_persistent);
obj->Set(...);
```

(To be nitpicky: `Local` doesn't have a `Set` method either; what it does have is an `operator->` overload that lets you call methods (including `Set`) on the thing that the Local refers to. If that thing isn't a `v8::Object` but e.g. a `v8::Number`, then it won't have a `Set` method.)

Comment: Thank you! What about performance? I will have to do this in a tight loop over and over again. Is creating a Local out of Persistent gonna be expensive?
In general, why doesn't Persistent class overload -> operator?

Comment: I'm not sure why `Persistent` doesn't offer more; I guess it's assumed to be rare. Creating a `Local` is cheap but not free; when in doubt try several approaches and measure if there's a difference for your use case. `HandleScope` creation and destruction is somewhat expensive; OTOH overly long-lived HandleScopes aren't great either; I'd use nested loops to create a fresh HandleScope every 1000 or so iterations of the inner loop.